# java replaceAll()

Tags: java, string

What is the regular expression for `replaceAll()` function to replace "N/A" with "0" ?

input  : `N/A`
output : `0`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming s is a `String`.

```
s.replaceAll("N/A", "0");
```

You don't even need regular expressions for that. This will suffice:

```
s.replace("N/A", "0");
```

Answer (score 8):

Why use a regular expression at all? If you don't need a pattern, just use `replace`:

```
String output = input.replace("N/A", "0");
```

Comment: The Java API describes the first argument as a regular expression. Hence the form of the question.

Comment: @SteveT: Yes, but my point is that there's no need to use `replaceAll` at all.

Comment: Ah - thanks. I didn't notice the different method you suggested. That's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a faster code. If the string contains only N/A:

```
return str.equals("N/A") ? "0" : str;
```

if string contains multiple N/A:

```
return join(string.split("N/A"), "0")
            + (string.endsWith("N/A") ? "0" : "");
```

where *join()* is method:

```
private String join(String[] split, String string) {
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
    boolean isNotFirst = false;
    for (String str : split) {
        if (isNotFirst) {
            s.append(string);
        } else {
            isNotFirst = true;
        }
        s.append(str);
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

it is twice as fast

Comment: I will assume your code works correctly, but what makes you think that calling `split()` plus `join()` is faster than `replace()` or regex?

Comment: I tested on large data sets. Unfortunately the test was lost. I think that you can make a new test in the new version of Java. It will be interesting to see the result. I will be glad to help you.