# How to replace comma (,) with a dot (.) using java

Tags: java, string

I am having a `String str = 12,12`
I want to replace the ,(comma) with  .(Dot) for decimal number calculation,
Currently i am trying this :

```
 if( str.indexOf(",") != -1 )
 {
     str.replaceAll(",","\\.");
 }
```

please help

Comment: You know that the method doesn't modify the String but returns the modified one, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java replaceAll()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092416/java-replaceall)

Answer (score 54):

Your problem is not with the match / replacement, but that String is immutable, you need to assign the result:

```
str = str.replaceAll(",","."); // or "\\.", it doesn't matter...
```

Comment: exactly that is the issue.

Answer (score 19):

Just use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` (which expects regex):

```
str = str.replace(",", ".");
```

or

```
str = str.replace(',', '.');
```

(`replace` takes as input either `char` or `CharSequence`, which is an interface implemented by `String`)

Also note that you should reassign the result

Answer (score 16):

```
str = str.replace(',', '.')
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(str.indexOf(",")!=-1) { str = str.replaceAll(",","."); }
```

or even better

```
str = str.replace(',', '.');
```

Comment: This: `"\."` will not compile

Answer (score 2):

Just use `str.replace(',', '.')` - it is both fast and efficient when a single character is to be replaced. And if the comma doesn't exist, it does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

For the current information you are giving, it will be enought with this simple regex to do the replacement:

```
str.replaceAll(",", ".");
```

Answer (score 1):

**in the java src you can add a new tool like this:**

```
public static String remplaceVirguleParpoint(String chaine) {
       return chaine.replaceAll(",", "\\.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
String str = " 12,12"
str = str.replaceAll("(\\d+)\\,(\\d+)", "$1.$2");
System.out.println("str:"+str); //-> str:12.12
```

hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it in general because you are from Europe and want to use dots instead of commas for reading an input with a scaner you can do it like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useLocale(Locale.US);
System.out.println(sc.locale().getDisplayCountry());
```

[Double accepted with comma instead of dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444631/double-accepted-with-comma-instead-of-dot)