# Double accepted with comma instead of dot

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting

I am unable to enter doubles value in my program from my bash terminal. Below is the code I used to figure out why it is happening.

This is my code for the test:

```
import java.util.*;
public class DoubleTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        double n = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(n);
    } 
}
```

With the following input 5, I get the expected results.

```
user $ java DoubleTest
   5
   5.0
```

Now to the interesting part. I input a Double as declared in the code, and this happens:

```
user $ java DoubleTest
5.0
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
at DoubleTest.main(DoubleTest.java:6)
```

And when giving a value of 5,0 - this is the result:

```
user $ java DoubleTest
5,0
5.0
```

So it seems that the `.` (dot) is not working, but instead `,` (comma) is.

I already checked my locale, but that shouldn't be the problem.

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Just to be sure: The usual format in Denmark is using a comma, right?

Comment: As RKrum pointed out: The `Scanner` will use the default locale. It's not clear where your information about your locale came from, but calling `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);` basically as "the first line of your `main` method" should be worth a try...

Answer (score 2):

Your `Scanner` is probably using the `Denmark` `Locale` as it uses `,` to format double variables instead of US default `.`.

Here is how you can check it (I tried locally forcing my Scanner to use Denmark Locale and it behaves the same way as in your experiments):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(sc.locale().getDisplayCountry());
```

If this is your case, you need to set it to use the US `Locale` or any other you want:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useLocale(Locale.US);
System.out.println(sc.locale().getDisplayCountry());
```

Alternatively, if you need to accept both `,` and `.` you could simply use a formatter. Here is one example with `NumberFormat` using `France` as Locale, which formats correctly both `,` and `.`:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
double doubleComma = numberFormat.parse("5,0").doubleValue();
double doubleDot = numberFormat.parse("5.0").doubleValue();
```

In your code you would do something like:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
        double n = numberFormat.parse(sc.next()).doubleValue();
        System.out.println(n);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Replacing *might* be a bit brittle. Depending on whether `.` or `,` is the standard separator, the number `1,234` might either mean `1.234` or `1234`. So before attempting to *fix* this issue, it might be worthwhile to figure out why it appears in the first place...

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the heads up! Changed my answer with some experiments

Comment: Thank you for the help. Would there be a way for me to set the US locale as default for my JVM? So I wouldn't have to explicitly define it in every program

Comment: user10991282 The Locale is determined in some different ways depending on your system settings. You can do some reading about it here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html#using

Comment: Alternatively, setting it using JVM arguments when launching your app should work. Example: "java -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -jar yourJar.jar"